# PHP preg_replace behaving unexpectedly with '$' in the subject

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have the following code:

```
echo preg_replace("/test/","$1000","this is a test");
```

I'm expecting this to print: "this is a $1000", but instead I'm getting "this s a 00".

This is a simplified example which pin-pointed the problem I'm running into at the moment. I can't use str_replace in this case. I also can't replace the '$' with '$#36', there is recursive functionality in my programming that is depending on a '$' to stay a '$' and '$#36' to stay '$#36'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a replacement string $ is used to write backreferences to capture groups, so you need to escape it.

```
echo preg_replace("/test/","\\$1000","this is a test");
```

in your original code `$10` was interpreted as a backreference to the capture group number 10 (that doesn't exist). Since the number of backreferences are limited to 99, only the two first digits are taken in account.

Answer (score 1):

`$1` is backreference to a capturing subpattern, that is anything, that is captured by parentheses. `$0` references the matched string itself, `$1` is the first matched by parentheses, etc. You don't have any capturing parentheses, so it's empty.

http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php